# Send AJAX-Request with text data (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send some Data with tha `$.ajax()`method from JQuery. The problem is, that the data (a string) include ";" and other special characters. The problem is, that ";" ist the separator for the key/value. How can i submit this over POST with jquery?

Here is the code:

```
$('#save_patterns').click(function() {
 $('#save_patterns').text('Saving ...')
 var code = $('#article_code').val() // include ";" and stuff
 $.ajax({url: '/extractor/save-patterns',
   type: 'POST', data: code,
   success: function(data) {
    $('#save_patterns').text('Save the patterns')
   }
 })
 return false
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#save_patterns').click(function() {
    $('#save_patterns').text('Saving ...')
    var code = $('#article_code').val() // include ";" and stuff
    $.ajax({url: '/extractor/save-patterns',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: { code: code },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#save_patterns').text('Save the patterns')
        }
    })
    return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
('#save_patterns').click(function() {
    $('#save_patterns').text('Saving ...')
    var code = $('#article_code').val() // include ";" and stuff
    $.ajax({ url: '/extractor/save-patterns',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: { code: JSON.stringify(code) },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#save_patterns').text('Save the patterns')
        }
    })
    return false
})
```

try this